# What is the difference between size and count in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, difference

That is the difference between `groupby("x").count` and `groupby("x").size` in pandas ?

Does size just exclude nil ?

Comment: Documentation said, that size "return number of elements in the NDFrame", and count "return Series with number of non-NA/null observations over requested axis. Works with non-floating point data as well (detects NaN and None)"

Comment: The accepted answer states the difference is including or excluding `NaN` values, it must be noted this is a secondary point. Compare outputs of `df.groupby('key').size()` and of `df.groupby('key').count()` for a DataFrame with multiple Series. The difference is obvious: `count` works like any other aggregate functions (`mean`, `max`...) but `size` is specific to getting the number of index entries in the group, and therefore doesn't look at values in columns which are meaningless for this function. See @cs95 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364400/774575) for an accurate explanation.

Comment: is count equivalent to set and size combined

Comment: Note that `df.size` and `series.size` are [not functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html#pandas-dataframe-size) so we cannot call them; whereas `GroupBy.size` is a function so we can call: `GroupBy.size()`.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

[`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) includes `NaN` values, [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count) does not:

```
In [46]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,1,2,2,2], 'b':[1,2,3,4,np.NaN,4], 'c':np.random.randn(6)})
df

Out[46]:
   a   b         c
0  0   1  1.067627
1  0   2  0.554691
2  1   3  0.458084
3  2   4  0.426635
4  2 NaN -2.238091
5  2   4  1.256943

In [48]:
print(df.groupby(['a'])['b'].count())
print(df.groupby(['a'])['b'].size())

a
0    2
1    1
2    2
Name: b, dtype: int64

a
0    2
1    1
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think that count also returns a DataFrame while size a Series?

Comment: .size() function get aggregated value of the particular column only  while .column() is used for every column.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D size returns an integer

Comment: @boardtc df.size returns a number - the groupby methods are discussed here, see the links in the question.

Comment: As for my question - count and size indeed return DataFrame and Series respectively when "bound" to a DataFrameGroupBy instance - in the question are bound to SeriesGroupBy so they both return a Series instance

Answer (score 67):

> ## What is the difference between size and count in pandas?

The other answers have pointed out the difference, however, it is **not completely accurate** to say "`size` counts NaNs while `count` does not". While `size` does indeed count NaNs, this is actually a consequence of the fact that **`size` returns the *size* (or the length) of the object** it is called on. Naturally, this also includes rows/values which are NaN.

So, to summarize, `size` returns the size of the Series/DataFrame<sup>1</sup>,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x', 'y', np.nan, 'z']})
df

     A
0    x
1    y
2  NaN
3    z
```

<!- _>

```
df.A.size
# 4
```

...while `count` counts the non-NaN values:

```
df.A.count()
# 3
```

Notice that `size` is an attribute (gives the same result as `len(df)` or `len(df.A)`). `count` is a function.

<sub>1. `DataFrame.size` is also an attribute and returns the number of elements in the DataFrame (rows x columns).</sub>

---

### Behaviour with `GroupBy` - Output Structure

Besides the basic difference, there's also the difference in the structure of the generated output when calling `GroupBy.size()` vs `GroupBy.count()`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': list('aaabbccc'),
    'B': ['x', 'x', np.nan, np.nan,
          np.nan, np.nan, 'x', 'x']
})

df
   A    B
0  a    x
1  a    x
2  a  NaN
3  b  NaN
4  b  NaN
5  c  NaN
6  c    x
7  c    x
```

Consider,

```
df.groupby('A').size()

A
a    3
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64
```

Versus,

```
df.groupby('A').count()

   B
A   
a  2
b  0
c  2
```

`GroupBy.count` returns a DataFrame when you call `count` on all column, while `GroupBy.size` returns a Series.

The reason being that `size` is the same for all columns, so only a single result is returned. Meanwhile, the `count` is called for each column, as the results would depend on on how many NaNs each column has.

---

### Behavior with `pivot_table`

Another example is how `pivot_table` treats this data. Suppose we would like to compute the cross tabulation of

```
df

   A  B
0  0  1
1  0  1
2  1  2
3  0  2
4  0  0

pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B)  # Result we expect, but with `pivot_table`.

B  0  1  2
A         
0  1  2  1
1  0  0  1
```

With `pivot_table`, you can issue `size`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

B  0  1  2
A         
0  1  2  1
1  0  0  1
```

But `count` does not work; an empty DataFrame is returned:

```
df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', aggfunc='count')

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1]
```

I believe the reason for this is that `'count'` must be done on the series that is passed to the `values` argument, and when nothing is passed, pandas decides to make no assumptions.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add a little bit to @Edchum's answer, even if the data has no NA values, the result of count() is more verbose, using the example before:

```
grouped = df.groupby('a')
grouped.count()
Out[197]: 
   b  c
a      
0  2  2
1  1  1
2  2  3
grouped.size()
Out[198]: 
a
0    2
1    1
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: It seems `size` is elegant equivalent of `count` in pandas.

Comment: @QM.py NO, it isn't. The reason for the difference in the `groupby` output is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364400/4909087).

Answer (score 1):

When we are dealing with normal dataframes then only difference will be an inclusion of NAN values, means count does not include NAN values while counting rows.

But if we are using these functions with the `groupby` then, to get the correct results by `count()` we have to associate any numeric field with the `groupby` to get the exact number of groups where for `size()` there is no need for this type of association.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all above answers, I would like to point out one more difference which I find significant.

You can correlate `pandas`' `DataFrame` size and count with Java's `Vectors` size and length. When we create a vector, some predefined memory is allocated to it. When we reach closer to the maximum number of elements it can hold, more memory is allocated to accommodate further additions. Similarly, in `DataFrame` as we add elements, the memory allocated to it increases.

The `size` attribute gives the number of memory cell allocated to `DataFrame` whereas `count` gives the number of elements that are actually present in `DataFrame`. For example,
[image]

You can see that even though there are 3 rows in `DataFrame`, its size is 6.

This answer covers size and count difference with respect to `DataFrame` and not `pandas` `Series`. I have not checked what happens with `Series`.