# ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '5B'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

What I understood of this error is that it means that there is a column that is of type long(). But this column contains a value named '5B' which isn't a long type.

This is the line where the error occurs:

```
df_Company = df1.groupby(by=['manufacturer','quality_issue'], as_index=False) ['quality_issue2'].count()
```

I have checked all the column types of the dataframe df1. But there are no columns with the type long. 5B is a name of a manufacturer so I assume that the column manufacturer has suddenly became of type long during this sentence.

checked what types the dataframe df1 has.

```
print (df1.dtypes)
manufacturer                    object
yearweek                         int64
quality_issue                   object
quality_issue2                  object
```

I 'think' I have to do something with `df_Company.astype(long)` but it seems I can't make it work. Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Note: the strange thing is that on my other computer where I have Python 3.5.1 the same code works just fine. but when I run the code on my current computer where I have Python 2.7.9 I get this long error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is different, see [8381](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8381), but in my pandas version `0.18.1` it works nice.

I think you can change `False` to `True` and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df_Company=df1.groupby(by=['manufacturer','quality_issue'], as_index=True)['quality_issue2']
              .count()
              .reset_index()
```

Differences between [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html) (see [differences with numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33346694/2901002)):

Sample with `string` values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame([['foo','foo','bar','bar','bar','oats'],
                  ['foo','foo','bar','bar','bar','oats'],
                  [None,'foo','bar',None,'bar','oats']]).T
df1.columns=['manufacturer','quality_issue','quality_issue2']
print (df1)
  manufacturer quality_issue quality_issue2
0          foo           foo           None
1          foo           foo            foo
2          bar           bar            bar
3          bar           bar           None
4          bar           bar            bar
5         oats          oats           oats

df_Company=df1.groupby(by=['manufacturer','quality_issue'], as_index=False)['quality_issue2']
              .count()
print (df_Company)

  manufacturer quality_issue  quality_issue2
0          bar           bar               2
1          foo           foo               1
2         oats          oats               1

df_Company1=df1.groupby(by=['manufacturer','quality_issue'])['quality_issue2']
               .size()
               .reset_index(name='quality_issue2')
print (df_Company1)

  manufacturer quality_issue  quality_issue2
0          bar           bar               3
1          foo           foo               2
2         oats          oats               1
```

I think you can omit `[quality_issue2]`, output is same:

```
df_Company1=df1.groupby(by=['manufacturer','quality_issue'])
               .size()
               .reset_index(name='quality_issue2')
print (df_Company1)
  manufacturer quality_issue  quality_issue2
0          bar           bar               3
1          foo           foo               2
2         oats          oats               1
```

Comment: Btw, you need `count`? Not `size`?

Comment: [differences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33346694/2901002): [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) includes `NaN` values, [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count) does not

Comment: What I was trying to do was to group by manufacturers, and see which issues the manufacturers had. And then count how many issues did each manufacturer had of those quality_issues. Therefore I think it is better to do count in place of size (right?). Basically the quality_issue and quality_issue2 columns have the exact same data in them.

Comment: See edit, I try explain by sample. Good luck and thank you for accepting.