# python pandas simple pivot table sum count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I'm trying to identify the best way to make a simple pivot on my data:

```
import pandas    
dfn = pandas.DataFrame({
    "A" : [ 'aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'bbb' ],
    "B" : [     1,    10,     2,   30  ],
    "C" : [     2,     0,     3,   20  ] })
```

The output I would like to have is a dataframe, grouped by `A`, that sum and count values of `B` and `C`, and names have to be exactly (`Sum_B`, `Sum_C`, `Count`), as following:

```
A   Sum_B  Sum_C  Count
aaa    3      5       2
bbb   50     20       2
```

What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: also I'm guessing `bbb` `Sum_B` should be 40 not 50 right?

Answer (score 6):

you can use [.agg()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) function:

```
In [227]: dfn.groupby('A').agg({'B':sum, 'C':sum, 'A':'count'}).rename(columns={'A':'count'})
Out[227]:
      B  count   C
A
aaa   3      2   5
bbb  40      2  20
```

or with `reset_index()`:

```
In [239]: dfn.groupby('A').agg({'B':sum, 'C':sum, 'A':'count'}).rename(columns={'A':'count'}).reset_index()
Out[239]:
     A   B  count   C
0  aaa   3      2   5
1  bbb  40      2  20
```

PS Here is a [link](http://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/) to examples provided by [@evan54](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1764089/evan54)

Comment: didn't know about `agg` (aggregate), this is a nice description http://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/

Comment: I add also .reset_index() in order to "move" 'A' to a column, since i have to write a csv

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) with double `sum` and `len`, [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) columns and last change order of columns by [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
print (dfn.groupby('A')
          .agg({'B': sum, 'C':sum, 'A':len})
          .rename(columns={'A': 'Count', 'B': 'Sum_B', 'C': 'Sum_C'})
          .reindex_axis(['Sum_B','Sum_C','Count'], axis=1))  

     Sum_B  Sum_C  Count
A                       
aaa      3      5      2
bbb     40     20      2
```

If need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (dfn.groupby('A')
          .agg({'B': sum, 'C':sum, 'A':len})
          .rename(columns={'A': 'Count', 'B': 'Sum_B', 'C': 'Sum_C'})
          .reindex_axis(['Sum_B','Sum_C','Count'], axis=1)
          .reset_index())  

     A  Sum_B  Sum_C  Count
0  aaa      3      5      2
1  bbb     40     20      2
```

Instead `len` you can use `size`, what is same:

```
print (dfn.groupby('A')
          .agg({'B': sum, 'C':sum, 'A':'size'})
          .rename(columns={'A': 'Count', 'B': 'Sum_B', 'C': 'Sum_C'})
          .reindex_axis(['Sum_B','Sum_C','Count'], axis=1)
          .reset_index())  

     A  Sum_B  Sum_C  Count
0  aaa      3      5      2
1  bbb     40     20      2
```

Differences between [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html) (see [differences with numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33346694/2901002)):

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to group by the column you want and then sum as shown below.

```
r = dfn.groupby('A').sum()
r['counts'] = dfn.A.value_counts() # this could also be written as dfn['A'].value_counts()
```

The first line computes the sums and the second line gets the number of times each of the values appears in A.