# How to .value_count() rows while taking into account other columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  date   post 
   da1     a 
   da1     b
   da2     a
   da3     c
   da1     d
   da1     a
```

What I want to do is this:

```
    date post total
     da1   a     2
     da1   b     1
     da2   a     1
     da3   c     1
     da1   d     1
```

I've tried:

```
    df.groupby(["date","post"]).count().sort_values(['index'], ascending=0)
```

And it sorts it in that order, but I cannot then access the date/post values via: **df.date** or **df.post** anymore as all the dates/posts become their own "keys" to the values in total.

It is imperative that I can access the values in the columns via their headers- how should I go about doing this?

Comment: call `reset_index()` on the result: `df.groupby(["date","post"]).count().sort_values(['index'], ascending=0).result_index()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print (df.groupby(["date","post"]).size().reset_index(name='total'))
  date post  total
0  da1    a      2
1  da1    b      1
2  da1    d      1
3  da2    a      1
4  da3    c      1
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Comment: do you even need `sort_index()`?