# Issue with joining repeated values/rows

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pandas-groupby

New to python, can't seem to understand how to proceed.
After using bin and editing my data frame I was able to come up with this :

```
    Continents  % Renewable Country
0   Asia    (15.753, 29.227]    China
1   North America   (2.212, 15.753] United States
2   Asia    (2.212, 15.753] Japan
3   Europe  (2.212, 15.753] United Kingdom
4   Europe  (15.753, 29.227]    Russian Federation
5   North America   (56.174, 69.648]    Canada
6   Europe  (15.753, 29.227]    Germany
7   Asia    (2.212, 15.753] India
8   Europe  (15.753, 29.227]    France
9   Asia    (2.212, 15.753] South Korea
10  Europe  (29.227, 42.701]    Italy
11  Europe  (29.227, 42.701]    Spain
12  Asia    (2.212, 15.753] Iran
13  Australia   (2.212, 15.753] Australia
14  South America   (56.174, 69.648]    Brazil
```

Now when I set the Continents and % Renewable as a miltiindex using :

```
Top15 = Top15.groupby(by=['Continents', '% Renewable']).sum()
```

to get the following:

```
                            Country
Continents  % Renewable   
Asia    (15.753, 29.227]    China
         (2.212, 15.753]    JapanIndiaSouth KoreaIran
Australia   (2.212, 15.753] Australia
Europe  (15.753, 29.227]    Russian FederationGermanyFrance
        (2.212, 15.753] United Kingdom
        (29.227, 42.701]    ItalySpain
North America   (2.212, 15.753] United States
                 (56.174, 69.648]   Canada
South America   (56.174, 69.648]    Brazil
```

Now I would like to have a column that would give me the number of countries in each index ie:

In the 1st Row - China =1 ,

and in the 2nd Row JapanIndiaSouth KoreaIran would be 4

So in the end I want something like this :

```
Asia           (2.212, 15.753]     4
               (15.753, 29.227]    1
```

I just don't know how to get there.

Also, the numbers need to be sorted in descending order, while still keeping the index grouping in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Top15.groupby(['Continents', '% Renewable']).Country.count()

Continents     % Renewable     
Asia           (15.753, 29.227]    1
               (2.212, 15.753]     4
Australia      (2.212, 15.753]     1
Europe         (15.753, 29.227]    3
               (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (29.227, 42.701]    2
North America  (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
South America  (56.174, 69.648]    1
Name: Country, dtype: int64
```

---

To sort in the order you'd like

```
Top15_count = Top15.groupby(['Continents', '% Renewable']).Country.count()

Top15_count.reset_index() \
    .sort_values(
        ['Continents', 'Country'],
        ascending=[True, False]
    ).set_index(['Continents', '% Renewable']).Country

Continents     % Renewable     
Asia           (2.212, 15.753]     4
               (15.753, 29.227]    1
Australia      (2.212, 15.753]     1
Europe         (15.753, 29.227]    3
               (29.227, 42.701]    2
               (2.212, 15.753]     1
North America  (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
South America  (56.174, 69.648]    1
Name: Country, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you , but Is there a way to have it be descending order ? like in case of Asia the 4 be the first row and 1 be the next.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `size`:

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

```
print (Top15.groupby(['Continents', '% Renewable']).size())
Name: Country, dtype: int64
Continents     % Renewable     
Asia           (15.753, 29.227]    1
               (2.212, 15.753]     4
Australia      (2.212, 15.753]     1
Europe         (15.753, 29.227]    3
               (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (29.227, 42.701]    2
North America  (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
South America  (56.174, 69.648]    1
dtype: int64
```

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) if need change order and for dataframe add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), last if need `MultiIndex` add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print (Top15.groupby(['Continents', '% Renewable']) \
            .size() \
            .reset_index(name='COUNT') \
            .sort_values(['Continents', 'COUNT'], ascending=[True, False]) \
            .set_index(['Continents','% Renewable']).COUNT)

Continents     % Renewable     
Asia           (2.212, 15.753]     4
               (15.753, 29.227]    1
Australia      (2.212, 15.753]     1
Europe         (15.753, 29.227]    3
               (29.227, 42.701]    2
               (2.212, 15.753]     1
North America  (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
South America  (56.174, 69.648]    1
Name: COUNT, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you , but Is there a way to have it be descending order ? like in case of Asia the 4 be the first row and 1 be the next.

Comment: Sorry, for this but i need the Asia 4 and asia 1 to be together, ie first row to be asia with value 4 then 1 , and after that Australia with row with value 3 then 2 then 1. Basically index gets first priority in sorting a-z, and then the values after that.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! got the answer!