# In Pandas, after groupby the grouped column is gone

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe named ttm:

```
    usersidid   clienthostid    eventSumTotal   LoginDaysSum    score
0       12          1               60              3           1728
1       11          1               240             3           1331
3       5           1               5               3           125
4       6           1               16              2           216
2       10          3               270             3           1000
5       8           3               18              2           512
```

When i do

```
ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], as_index=False, sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].count()
```

I get what I expected (though I would've wanted the results to be under a new label named 'ratio'):

```
       clienthostid  LoginDaysSum
0             1          4
1             3          2
```

But when I do

```
ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], as_index=False, sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1])
```

I get:

```
0    1.0
1    1.5
```

1. Why did the labels go? I still also need the grouped need the 'clienthostid' and I need also the results of the apply to be under a label too
2. Sometimes when I do groupby some of the other columns still appear, why is that that sometimes columns disappear and sometime stays? is there a flag I'm missing that do those stuff?
3. In the example that I gave, when I did count the results showed on label 'LoginDaysSum', is there a why to add a new label for the results instead?

Thank you,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For return `DataFrame` after `groupby` are 2 possible solutions:

1. parameter `as_index=False` what works nice with `count`, `sum`, `mean` functions
2. [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for create new column from levels of `index`, more general solution

```
df = ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], as_index=False, sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].count()
print (df)
   clienthostid  LoginDaysSum
0             1             4
1             3             2
```

```
df = ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].count().reset_index()
print (df)
   clienthostid  LoginDaysSum
0             1             4
1             3             2
```

---

For second need remove `as_index=False` and instead add `reset_index`:

```
#output is `Series`
a = ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'] \
         .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1])
print (a)
clienthostid
1    1.0
3    1.5
Name: LoginDaysSum, dtype: float64

print (type(a))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (a.index)
Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64', name='clienthostid')


df1 = ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], sort=False)['LoginDaysSum']
         .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1]).reset_index(name='ratio')
print (df1)
   clienthostid  ratio
0             1    1.0
1             3    1.5
```

Why some columns are gone?

I think there can be problem [automatic exclusion of nuisance columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns):

```
#convert column to str
ttm.usersidid = ttm.usersidid.astype(str) + 'aa'
print (ttm)
  usersidid  clienthostid  eventSumTotal  LoginDaysSum  score
0      12aa             1             60             3   1728
1      11aa             1            240             3   1331
3       5aa             1              5             3    125
4       6aa             1             16             2    216
2      10aa             3            270             3   1000
5       8aa             3             18             2    512

#removed str column userid
a = ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], sort=False).sum()
print (a)
              eventSumTotal  LoginDaysSum  score
clienthostid                                    
1                       321            11   3400
3                       288             5   1512
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Comment: I think the OP has found a bug.

Comment: @chrisaycock - it seems it is not bug.

Answer (score 8):

`count` is a built in method for the `groupby` object and pandas knows what to do with it.  There are two other things specified that goes into determining what the out put looks like.

```
#                         For a built in method, when
#                         you don't want the group column
#                         as the index, pandas keeps it in
#                         as a column.
#                             |----||||----|
ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], as_index=False, sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].count()

   clienthostid  LoginDaysSum
0             1             4
1             3             2
```

---

```
#                         For a built in method, when
#                         you do want the group column
#                         as the index, then...
#                             |----||||---|
ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], as_index=True, sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].count()
#                                                       |-----||||-----|
#                                                 the single brackets tells
#                                                 pandas to operate on a series
#                                                 in this case, count the series

clienthostid
1    4
3    2
Name: LoginDaysSum, dtype: int64
```

---

```
ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], as_index=True, sort=False)[['LoginDaysSum']].count()
#                                                       |------||||------|
#                                             the double brackets tells pandas
#                                                to operate on the dataframe
#                                              specified by these columns and will
#                                                return a dataframe

              LoginDaysSum
clienthostid              
1                        4
3                        2
```

---

When you used `apply` pandas no longer knows what to do with the group column when you say `as_index=False`.  It has to trust that if you use `apply` you want returned exactly what you say to return, so it will just throw it away.  Also, you have single brackets around your column which says to operate on a series.  Instead, use `as_index=True` to keep the grouping column information in the index.  Then follow it up with a `reset_index` to transfer it from the index back into the dataframe.  At this point, it will not have mattered that you used single brackets because after the `reset_index` you'll have a dataframe again.

```
ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], as_index=True, sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1])

0    1.0
1    1.5
dtype: float64
```

---

```
ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], as_index=True, sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1]).reset_index()

   clienthostid  LoginDaysSum
0             1           1.0
1             3           1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [groupy documentarion](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html), a found out that automatic exclusion of columns after groupby usually caused by the presence of null values in that columns excluded.

Try fill the 'null' with some value.

Like this:

```
df.fillna('')
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need this instead:

```
ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], as_index=False, sort=False)[['LoginDaysSum']].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1]).reset_index()
```

The double `[[]]` will turn the output into a pd.Dataframe instead of a pd.Series.