# How can I make the groups in a specific column appear when the groupby method is used in order to merge?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
x=df.groupby(['id_gamer'])[['sucess', 'nb_games']].shift(periods=1).cumsum()
                            .apply(lambda row: row.sucess/row.nb_games, axis=1)
```

In the code above, I make a `groupby` on a `pandas.DataFrame` in order to obtain a shifted column of results represented as ratio, for each gamer, and each game. Actually his rate of success considering the number of games he played.

It returns a `pandas.core.series.Series` object as:

```
+---------------+----------------+
|     Index     | Computed_ratio |
+---------------+----------------+
| id_game_date  | NaN            |
| id_game2_date | 0.30           |
| id_game3_date | 0.40           |
| id_game_date  | NaN            |
| id_game4_date | 0.50           |
| ...           | ...            |
+---------------+----------------+
```

So, you may see the `NaN` as the delimitation between gamers. As you may see the first gamer and the second one met in one game: `id_game_date`. And this is why I would prefer the column of gamer from `id_gamer` to appear in order to merge it with the dataframe where data are from.

To be honest I have an idea of solution: just do not use the id of games as index, then each row will be indexed correctly and there is no conflict when I proceed a merge, I guess. But I would like to know if it is possible with this current pattern shown here.

*NB: I already tried with the solutions presented in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658498/in-pandas-after-groupby-the-grouped-column-is-gone). But none of these work, certainly because the functions shown are aggregations and not mine: cumsum(). If I used an aggregating function like sum() (with a different pattern of code, do not try with the one I gave you or it will return an error) the `id_gamer` appears. But it is not corresponding to my expectations.*