# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'Label': list('AABCCC'), 'Values':  [1,2,3,4,np.nan,8] })
```

I want to drop those groups that do not have a minimum number of items (one or less) so I tried the following:

```
f = lambda x: x.Values.count() > 1

df.groupby('Label').filter(f)
```

However, this raised an error:

> Error : 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'

Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Try this: `df.groupby('Label').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you have no `Values` but `values` column, so need add `[]` because collision with [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) function.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'values': [1,2,3,4,np.nan,8] })
print (df)
   values
0     1.0
1     2.0
2     3.0
3     4.0
4     NaN
5     8.0

#return numpy array
print (df.values)
[[  1.]
 [  2.]
 [  3.]
 [  4.]
 [ nan]
 [  8.]]

#select column values
print (df['values'])
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    NaN
5    8.0
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

Your solution for me works nice, I also change `.Values` to `['Values']`.

```
df1 = df.groupby('Label').filter(lambda x: x['Values'].count() > 1)
print (df1)
  Label  Values
0     A     1.0
1     A     2.0
3     C     4.0
4     C     NaN
5     C     8.0
```

Alternative solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.groupby('Label')['Values'].transform('count'))
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
Name: Values, dtype: float64

print (df.groupby('Label')['Values'].transform('count') > 1)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: Values, dtype: bool

print (df[df.groupby('Label')['Values'].transform('count') > 1])
  Label  Values
0     A     1.0
1     A     2.0
3     C     4.0
4     C     NaN
5     C     8.0
```

Also check [What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Comment: Thank you for accepting. Btw, in my opinion select with `.` is nicer and faster, but then no column `values`, `sum`, `count`, `mean` because `.sum`, `.values`... return pandas functions. So safer is use `[]` and then all column names works perfectly. Nice day and good luck!