# how to get the pulse width of an audio file in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, list, audio

I read a .wav file using the read function of the soundfile library in Python. I was wondering if there is any function to get the number of pulses of this signal, something like the [pulsewidth](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pulsewidth.html) function in Matlab.

If not, given that I did

```
[data,fs]=sf.read(wave)
```

I'm also trying something like this:

```
y=data2.count(data2>0.5)
```

but I'm getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751662/numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-count)

Comment: Isn't pulse width the inverse of sampling rate? `data, samplerate = sf.read('existing_file.wav')`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz each pulse can have a different duration, so nope :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **scipy.signal.find_peaks** can be of use to you.

With a numpy array as input, you can get the indices of the peaks, their widths ... etc