# Pandas aggregating category counts by user

Tags: python, pandas

How does one use pandas to create frequency counts for each user for each category. I would like to do this so I can pivot to create a utility matrix

```
|--|**author** | **category**|   
0|  A | movies  
1|  B | games  
2|  C | pics  
4|  A | movies  
5|  C | movies  
6|  B | games 




|--|**author** | **category count**|   

A | movies |2 |  
B | games  |2 |  
C | movies |1 |  
C | pics   |1 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for getting length of all categories in columns `author` and `category` - output is `Series` with `MultiIndex`.

```
print (df.groupby(['author','category']).size())
author  category
A       movies      2
B       games       2
C       movies      1
        pics        1
dtype: int64
```

Then add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for creating columns from `MultiIndex` and set column name for value column - output is `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.groupby(['author','category']).size().reset_index(name='category count')
print (df)
  author category  category count
0      A   movies               2
1      B    games               2
2      C   movies               1
3      C     pics               1
```

But if need [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) there is multiple solutions:

```
#add unstack for reshape
df1 = df.groupby(['author','category']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
category  games  movies  pics
author                       
A             0       2     0
B             2       0     0
C             0       1     1
```

---

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['author'],df['category'])
print (df1)
category  games  movies  pics
author                       
A             0       2     0
B             2       0     0
C             0       1     1
```

---

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='author',columns='category', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
print (df1)
category  games  movies  pics
author                       
A             0       2     0
B             2       0     0
C             0       1     1
```

EDIT:

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for a working solution. You even went the extra mile to show me the code for the utility matrix. If you didn't mind you could explain, why using the size/reset index does what it does?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: I try add some explanation, maybe also help [10min to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) and [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html). If something unclear, I try explain more.

Comment: Thank you! [size] (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) has no description on the documentation so I was pretty confused, but it make sense. Although I think that is a odd named method

Comment: Yes, there is also count function, but it ia a bit different. See last edit, I add link for better explanation.