# Applying a custom function on Group By if row count greater than 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How do i apply a function to a dataframe after grouping it if i only want to apply the function on groups where the group has membership greater than 1.

e.g

```
 df1 = df.groupyby(['x','y']).count() > 1.apply(f)

 f(x) :
   do something
```

Secondly what is being passed into the function - is it the elements on the group or the group itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `size`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['x','y']).size()

df1[df1 > 1] =  df1[df1 > 1].apply(f)
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,3],
                   'y':[5,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   C  x  y
0  7  1  5
1  8  1  5
2  9  3  6

def f(x) :
   return x + 2
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['x','y']).size()

s = df1[df1.COUNT > 1].set_index('x')['y']
print (s)
x
1    5
Name: y, dtype: int64

mask = df.set_index('x')['y'].isin(s).values
print (mask)
[ True  True False]

df[mask] = df[mask].apply(f)
print (df)
    C  x  y
0   9  3  7
1  10  3  7
2   9  3  6
```

Comment: in the function i do this : mask = x[K.side1].isin(x[K.side2]) | x[K.s2ide].isin(x[K.side1]). I get this error
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Hmm, problem is with `x[K.side1]` - Can you add some date sample ansd explain what need? Or `K.side1` is `dict` and return scalar? Or it is `Series` ?

Comment: becuse it need `x['col']`, but it is no problem if it is get dynamically.

Comment: so simply need `Series` or `column` of `df` from `x[K.side1]`

Comment: so x[K.side1] = x['colname'] basically K.side1 is a column name

Comment: Please check edited answer, I try use your code, but still not 100% sure if it is what you want. If some problem, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks i think the problem is. When i am using size it gets rid of every other column and keeps only the grouped columns and a size value. What i want is the whole of the original dataframe passed into the function groupedby x,y and where the group has more than one element

Comment: Ok, I remove unnecesary code and edit question, please check it.