# get rows based on a condition and separate them into subsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

am trying to subset a dataset based on a condition and pick the rows until it sees the value based on a condition

Condition, if Column A == 0, column B should start with 'a'.

Dataset:

```
A   B
0   aa
1   ss
2   dd
3   ff
0   ee
1   ff
2   bb
3   gg
0   ar
1   hh
2   ww
0   jj
1   ll
```

expected:

```
[0:{'A':[0,1,2,3], 'B':['aa','ss','dd','ff']}, 1:{'A':[0,1,2], 'B':['ar','hh,'ww']} ]
```

The series starts from column A == 0 and ends until the next 0.
In total there are 4 different dictionaries in that dataframe.

Comment: should groups be `df['A'].eq(0).cumsum().sub(1)` ? @pylearner

Comment: no, this isnt providing me results

Comment: Could you show an example for which this does not work? @pylearner

Comment: @ansev, I guess you havnet gone through my updated question

Comment: I've lost track of the conditions for your expected output. Can you update your question to contain the final clarifications?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, updated my question and expected output

Answer (score 2):

Do a cumsum on the condition to identify the groups, then groupby:

```
groups = (df['A'].eq(0) & df['B'].str.startswith('a')).cumsum()

{k:v.to_dict(orient='list') for k,v in df.groupby(groups)}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff']},
 2: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['ae', 'ff', 'bb', 'gg']},
 3: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1], 'B': ['ar', 'hh', 'ww', 'jj', 'll']}}
```

Comment: woah, This was fast. Thanks.

Comment: can we use a condition ? like if the column value A==0, then column B startswith 'a' ?

Comment: This isnt breaking into groups

Comment: changed the data, I guess now you might get my point.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny oh, yes, sure. I was talking about the second solution, which is more relevant to change of condition. I should have mentioned that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @pylearner see the above comment, also the modified answer this time.

Comment: can you paste your output as well ?

Comment: I have only three dictionaries this time

Comment: hey, the 3rd dictionary in your list is wrong, I dont want that to include ...where column A = 0, and column B doesnt starts with 'a'

Answer (score 2):

May be try with `cumsum` as well ~

```
{x : y.to_dict('list')for x , y in df.groupby(df['A'].eq(0).cumsum())}
Out[87]: 
{1: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff']},
 2: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['ee', 'ff', 'bb', 'gg']},
 3: {'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['rr', 'hh', 'ww']},
 4: {'A': [0, 1], 'B': ['jj', 'll']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers this question's `revision 2020-11-04 19:29:39Z`. Later additions/edits to the question or additional requirements in the comments will not be considered.

First find the desired rows and select them into a new dataframe. Group the rows and convert them to dicts.

```
g = (df.A.eq(0).astype(int) + df.B.str.startswith('a')).replace(0, method='ffill') - 1
df_BeqA = df[g.astype('bool')]

{x: y.to_dict('list') for x , y in df_BeqA.groupby(df_BeqA.A.eq(0).cumsum() - 1)}
```

Out:

```
{0: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff']},
 1: {'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['ar', 'hh', 'ww']}}
```