# Histogram on Pandas groupby with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have datafrme on which I perform groupby on two columns:

```
ax = df_all.groupby(['Component', 'SubComponent' ])['SubComponent'].count()
```

And this give me this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Component | SubComponent|                      |
--------------------------------------------------
|A          |First        |                     1|
--------------------------------------------------
|           |Second       |                    10|
--------------------------------------------------
|           |Third        |                     6|
--------------------------------------------------
|B          |First        |                     8|
--------------------------------------------------
|           |Second       |                     5|
--------------------------------------------------
|           |Third        |                    17|
--------------------------------------------------
```

Now I would like to make a histogram out of it.
Each bar would be Component and each component would divided on SubComponents showing number of occurrence of each SubComponent with different color.

Is there easy way to accomplish it with matplotlib.pyploy ?

Thanks,
Submi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
print (ax.unstack())
SubComponent  First  Second  Third
Component                         
A                 1       4     15
B                 6       2      1

ax.unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: graph]

---

```
print (ax.unstack(0))
Component      A  B
SubComponent       
First          1  6
Second         4  2
Third         15  1

ax.unstack(0).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: graph3]

*Notice*:

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Comment: Do you possible know why I'm not able to change size of this plot using: plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8)) on it?

Comment: Try `ax.unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10, 8))`