# Pandas: How do I get a column of group counts that fills in each row of the group?

Tags: python, pandas

I can successfully fill my new column with group counts, but I suspect there is a simpler way:

```
# How do I simplify this?

def f(gr):

    return pd.Series([gr['class_name'].count()] * gr.shape[0], index=gr.index)

df['class_size'] = df.groupby("class_name").apply(f).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
column_list = ['class_name', 'class_size']
df[column_list].head(5)
```

Gets:

[image: This is just the first few rows of data - see how the same class name has the same class count?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['class_size'] = df.groupby('class_name')['class_name'].transform('size')
```

Or:

```
df['class_size'] = df.groupby('class_name')['class_name'].transform('count')
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Comment: Works great - thanx!

Comment: Glad can help, also added differences between size and count to answer. nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DataFrame shape you can also just do a count on the groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'class names':list('abracadabra'),'class count':1})
df.groupby('class names').count().reset_index()
```