# Pandas: getting rid of the multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After grouping and counting a dataframe I'm trying to remove the multiindex like this:

```
df = df[['CID','FE', 'FID']].groupby(by=['CID','FE']).count()
              .unstack().reset_index()
```

Printing the columns (`df.colums`) shows that it is still a `MultiIndex`.

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['FID', 'CID'], [...]]
```

I can't access the column `CID` via `df['CID']`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think you need if is necessary convert `MultiIndex` to `Index`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
```

Or if need remove level use [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

If need access to values is possible use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df = df.xs('CID', axis=1, level=1)
```

You can also check:

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

EDIT:

For remove MultiIndex is another solution select by `['FID']`.

```
df = df.groupby(by=['CID','FE'])['FID'].count().unstack().reset_index()
```

Samples (also added [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for nicer output):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CID':[2,2,3],
                   'FE':[5,5,6],
                   'FID':[1,7,9]})

print (df)
   CID  FE  FID
0    2   5    1
1    2   5    7
2    3   6    9

df = df.groupby(by=['CID','FE'])['FID']
       .count()
       .unstack()
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print (df)    
   CID    5    6
0    2  2.0  NaN
1    3  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: The following works well for me:
``df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x[1])``
``df = df.reset_index()``
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should get rid of MultiIndex for CID and allow you to access it via df['CID']

```
df = df.rename(columns={('CID',''):'CID'})
```