# grouping and plotting data by time in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file and I am trying to plot the average of some values per month. My csv file is structured as shown below, so I believe that I should group my data daily, then monthly in order to calculate the mean value.

```
timestamp,heure,lat,lon,impact,type
2007-01-01 00:00:00,13:58:43,33.837,-9.205,10.3,1
2007-01-02 00:00:00,00:07:28,34.5293,-10.2384,17.7,1
2007-01-02 00:00:00,23:01:03,35.0617,-1.435,-17.1,2
2007-01-03 00:00:00,01:14:29,36.5685,0.9043,36.8,1
2007-01-03 00:00:00,05:03:51,34.1919,-12.5061,-48.9,1
```

I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df= pd.read_csv("ave.txt", sep=',', names =["timestamp","heure","lat","lon","impact","type"])
daily = df.set_index('timestamp').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='timestamp', freq='D', axis=1), axis=1)['impact'].count()
monthly = daily.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).mean()
ax = monthly.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

But, I keep getting errors like this:

> KeyError: 'The grouper name timestamp is not found'

any ideas ??

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because you've set the `timestamp` column to `index`. Try removing `key='timestamp'` from `TimeGrouper()` or the `set_index` method and it should group as you expect:

```
daily = df.set_index('timestamp').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D', axis=1), axis=1)['impact'].count()
```

or

```
daily = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='timestamp', freq='D', axis=1), axis=1)['impact'].count()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , I did as you said and now i am getting this error : IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

Comment: What line does this occur on?

Comment: on this line : daily = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='timestamp', freq='D', axis=1), axis=1)['impact'].count()

Comment: Are you intentionally using `axis=1` in `groupby()`? Can you try without that argument and see if it's what you expect?

Comment: when i try without that argument , it gives another error : axis must be a DatetimeIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Also is necessary convert `timestamp` to `DataTimeindex` by parameter `parse_dates` and `index_col` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
names =["timestamp","heure","lat","lon","impact","type"]
data = pd.read_csv('fou.txt',names=names, parse_dates=['timestamp'],index_col=['timestamp'])
print (data.head())

#your code
daily = data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D'))['impact'].count()
monthly = daily.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).mean()
ax = monthly.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()

#more simpliest
daily = data.resample('D')['impact'].count()
monthly = daily.resample('M').mean()
ax = monthly.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

---

[image: graph]

Also check if really need `count`, not `size`.
[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

```
daily = data.resample('D')['impact'].size()
monthly = daily.resample('M').mean()
ax = monthly.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you, i did as you said and it gave me this error :  raise TypeError('Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex')
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex

Comment: skina@skina:~/Documents/density$ python moyenne.py
                        heure      lat       lon  impact  type
timestamp                                                     
timestamp               heure      lat       lon  impact  type
2007-01-01 00:00:00  13:58:43   33.837    -9.205    10.3     1
2007-01-02 00:00:00  00:07:28  34.5293  -10.2384    17.7     1
2007-01-02 00:00:00  23:01:03  35.0617    -1.435   -17.1     2
2007-01-03 00:00:00  01:14:29  36.5685    0.9043    36.8     1

Comment: Actually i have a big csv file, what i posted here is just a little sample of my data, how can I convert the whole csv file ?

Comment: your code is working fine, but it's not giving me the results i need.

Comment: i need to plot the average of impacts per month

Comment: i checked data for one month ,and it's giving this error : KeyError: 'the label [2017-01] is not in the [index]'

Comment: well i think that i am mistaken, i need to plot the average of impacts per month , but i have multiple lines of the same day but in different times (hours), so i need first to group data daily ( a day could has got a lot of impacts) , then group it monthly and plot it , so i believe i should take into consideration the second column which is heure. if you know what i mean.

Comment: my desired output, is to plot the month on x axix and mean of impacts per month on y axix

Comment: it's not working , it says  : raise TypeError('Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex')
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex

Comment: shall i send you my csv file to picture my data ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145640/discussion-between-marie-antoinette-and-jezrael).