# Python/Pandas - How to group by two columns and count rows with value from third column between two numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I need to group my data frame by two columns and after that count the occurrences of values from third column, which are between 1 and 20.

Data frame:

```
col1  col2  value
  a     b     1
  a     b     3
  a     b     22
  a     c     0
  a     c     3
  a     c     19
```

Result:

```
col1  col2  counter
 a     b      2
 a     c      2
```

My code:

```
counter = data_frame.groupby(['column1', 'column2'])[((data_frame['value'] >= 1) & (data_frame['value'] < 20))].sum()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need filter first by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = data_frame[(data_frame['value'] >= 1) & (data_frame['value'] < 20)]
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().reset_index(name='counter')
print (df)
  col1 col2  counter
0    a    b        2
1    a    c        2
```

Or:

```
df = data_frame.query('value >= 1 & value < 20')
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().reset_index(name='counter')
print (df)
  col1 col2  counter
0    a    b        2
1    a    c        2
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter those value first, then you can use the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and the [count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html)
functions like this :

```
df[(df.value<=20) & (df.value >= 1)].groupby(['col1','col2']).count().reset_index()
```

output :

```
    col1    col2    value
0   a       b       2
1   a       c       2


100 loops, best of 3: 2.5 ms per loop
```