# pandas plot of bar chart of postitive and negative values from a csv file

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

i have a csv file containing data, i have a column that contains positive and negative values and i need to plot the mean of this column in a way to have 2 bars , one for the negative values and one for the positive values.
Take a look on my data :

```
timestamp,heure,lat,lon,ampl,type
2006-01-01 00:00:00,13:58:43,33.837,-9.205,10.3,1
2006-01-02 00:00:00,00:07:28,34.5293,-10.2384,17.7,1
2007-02-01 00:00:00,23:01:03,35.0617,-1.435,-17.1,2
2007-02-02 00:00:00,01:14:29,36.5685,0.9043,36.8,1
....
2011-12-31 00:00:00,05:03:51,34.1919,-12.5061,-48.9,1
```

i am using this code to plot my data :

```
names =["timestamp","heure","lat","lon","ampl","type"]
data = pd.read_csv('flash.txt',names=names, parse_dates=['timestamp'],index_col=['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)
data['ampl'] = data['ampl'].abs()
yearly = data.groupby(data.index.month)['ampl'].count()
ax = yearly.plot(kind='bar')
```

so, i need to disassociate the values of the column in question and have 2 bars instead of one , how can I proceed ?

Comment: Without data it is a bit problematic, but if change `yearly = data.groupby(data.index.month)['ampl'].count()` to `yearly = data.groupby([data.index.month, 'type'])['ampl'].count().unstack(fill_value)` it should work.

Comment: If it does not works, can you add 4-5 rows of sample data?

Comment: I just edited my question, you can take a look on my data now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create new column `sign` by [`numpy.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`.

Then add new column name to `groupby`, aggregate by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
data['sign'] = np.sign(data['ampl']).map({1:'+', -1:'-', 0:'0'})
data['ampl'] = data['ampl'].abs()
yearly = data.groupby([data.index.month, 'sign'])['ampl'].size().unstack()
yearly.plot(kind='bar')
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Comment: I did as you said, and I got this : KeyError: 'type'

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: it gives this : ['heure', 'lat', 'lon', 'ampl']

Comment: Hmmm, it is interesting, because in your sample is last column `type`. What if remove parameter `names`? Change `data = pd.read_csv('flash.txt',names=names, parse_dates=['timestamp'],index_col=['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)` to `data = pd.read_csv('flash.txt', parse_dates=['timestamp'],index_col=['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)`. Names is used, if no header in csv. How does it works now?

Comment: it's working now, but i just can't understand the meaning of the result, i'll send you the result via email since i don't have the right to share images ?

Comment: Sure, no problem.