# Getting the size of a groupby operation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been performing a groupby operation on a dataframe I have that aggregates columns together based on the column 'Name':

```
Name | As | Bs | Cs   |  Note
Mark   3     4     7     Good
Luke   2     1     12    Well
Mark   5     6     8     Ok
John   1     18    3     Great
```

So in this case, the rows with 'Mark' are aggregated together on columns A,B, and C using this code:

```
temp_df = temp_df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False).agg({'As': np.sum, 'Bs': np.sum,'Cs': np.sum})
```

A thing I need to add in is to do a count on the number of rows that have the same value in 'Name'. This would give me an output like:

```
Name | As | Bs | Cs   |  Note   | Count
Mark   8     10    15    Good      2
Luke   2     1     12    Well      1
John   1     18    3     Great     1
```

How do I modify the above line of code to do what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the group and do your aggregations:

```
the_group = temp_df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)
temp_df = the_group.agg({'As': np.sum, 'Bs': np.sum,'Cs': np.sum})
```

then compute the `size` from `the_group`

```
temp_df['count'] = the_group.count()['Note']
```

gives:

```
   Name  Cs  As  Bs  count
0  John   3   1  18      1
1  Luke  12   2   1      1
2  Mark  15   8  10      2
```

### Edit:

As suggested in the comments, it is safer to use `size()` in case the data include `NaN`:

```
temp_df['count'] = the_group.size().reset_index()[0]
```

Comment: I believe you meant to say 'temp_df['count'] = the_group.count()['Name']'? WHich is what I want to get. THis does not seem to be working though, I'm just getting back the string value for name for each row.

Comment: Count is used for check non NaN values, need size.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and then is necessary `rename` columns by dict:

```
temp_df = temp_df.groupby('Name', sort=False) \
                .agg({'As':np.sum,'Bs':np.sum,'Cs':np.sum,'Note':'first','Name':'size'}) \
                .rename(columns={'Name':'Count'}) \
                .reset_index() \
                .reindex_axis(temp_df.columns.tolist() + ['Count'], axis=1) 
print (temp_df)
   Name  As  Bs  Cs   Note  Count
0  Mark   8  10  15   Good      2
1  Luke   2   1  12   Well      1
2  John   1  18   3  Great      1
```

Dont use `count`, only `size` or `len`.

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Comment: Since pandas 0.25.0+ you can use named aggregation. 
temp_df.groupby('Name', sort=False).agg(As=('As','sum'),Bs=('Bs','sum'),Cs=('Cs','sum'),Note=('Note','first'),Count=('Name','size'))