# Pandas If function or groupby

Tags: python, pandas

New to Pandas. I had this code originally written to read .csv and now I am writing to read .xlsx files. Anyway, I used **if** function before to read if Valid Part == 'YES' then ..... follow rest of code.

Now that I am using Pandas I have been testing groupby to achieve my count but haven't quite figured it out.

I am looking in this example if Valid Part == 'Yes' and Appl Req == 'Yes' give me the count.

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('IMPORT.xlsx')

app_req = df.groupby(['Valid Part', 'Appl Req']).count()

print(app_req)
```

Sample of Data

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) first and then aggregate by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'Yes') & (df['Appl Req'] == 'Yes')]
app_req = df.groupby(['Valid Part', 'Appl Req']).size()
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

EDIT:

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['Yes','No'], size=(N,3)), 
                  columns=['Valid Part', 'Appl Req', 'A'])
print (df)
   Valid Part Appl Req    A
0         Yes      Yes   No
1          No       No   No
2         Yes      Yes  Yes
3         Yes      Yes   No
4         Yes      Yes  Yes
5         Yes       No  Yes
6         Yes       No  Yes
7          No      Yes  Yes
8         Yes       No   No
9          No      Yes  Yes
```

It seems you need only sum of `True` values:

```
print ((df['Valid Part'] == 'Yes') & (df['Appl Req'] == 'Yes'))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool

app_req = ((df['Valid Part'] == 'Yes') & (df['Appl Req'] == 'Yes')).sum()
print (app_req)
4
```

---

```
df = df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'Yes') & (df['Appl Req'] == 'Yes')]
app_req = df.groupby(['Valid Part', 'Appl Req']).size().reset_index(name='COUNT')
print (app_req)
  Valid Part Appl Req  COUNT
0        Yes      Yes      4
```

Comment: Missing a `df[`?

Comment: does this work the same if I already used df = to read my excel doc?

Comment: Sure, no problem. But try `3` if number and `'3'` if string.