# Pandas: Group by key of dict in column which contains dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

### My data

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': range(5),
    'c2': [
        {'k1': 'x-1', 'k2': 'z'}, 
        {'k1': 'x-2', 'k2': 'z1'},
        {'k1': 'x-3', 'k2': 'z1'},
        {'k1': 'y-1', 'k2': 'z'},
        {'k1': 'y-2', 'k2': 'z1'}
    ]
})
```

### My aim

Now, I would like to group by `'k1'`, which is a common key in all rows of column `'c2'`, which contains dictionaries. The grouping function would be `lambda x: x.split('-')[0]` to cut off the numbers following the dash.

The desired output is:

```
'x'     3
'y'     2
```

### Attempts

```
>>> df.groupby(df['c2']['k1'].str.split('-')[0]).count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2477, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 98, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4404)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4087)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 156, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5210)
KeyError: 'k1'
```

Apparently, I cannot index the key `k1` of the row `c2` by `df['c2']['k1']`.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, only need convert column with `dicts` to new `DataFrame`:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df['c2'].values.tolist()))
    k1  k2
0  x-1   z
1  x-2  z1
2  x-3  z1
3  y-1   z
4  y-2  z1

a = pd.DataFrame(df['c2'].values.tolist())['k1'].str.split('-').str[0]
print (a)
0    x
1    x
2    x
3    y
4    y
Name: k1, dtype: object

df = df.groupby(a).size().reset_index(name='len')
print (df)
  k1  len
0  x    3
1  y    2
```

Another solution is use `list comprehension` for groupby keys:

```
L = [x['k1'].split('-')[0] for x in df['c2']]
print (L)
['x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y']

df = df.groupby(L).size().rename_axis('k1').reset_index(name='len')
print (df)
  k1  len
0  x    3
1  y    2
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Solutions with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = a.value_counts().rename_axis('k1').reset_index(name='len')
print (df)
  k1  len
0  x    3
1  y    2
```

---

```
df = pd.Series(L).value_counts().rename_axis('k1').reset_index(name='len')
print (df)
  k1  len
0  x    3
1  y    2
```