# Python Pandas Create Dataframe using a text file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to use Pandas to create a dataframe from a raw text file. The file includes 3 Categories with items related to each category after the category name. I am able to create a series based on the Category but don't know how to associate each item type to their respective category and create a dataframe out of it. Below is my initial code along with the desired output of the dataframe. Can you please help direct me in the right way to do this?

```
category = ['Fruits', 'Vegetables', 'Meats']

items='''Fruits
apple
orange
pear
Vegetables
broccoli
squash
carrot
Meats
chicken
beef
lamb'''

Category = pd.Series()

i = 0
for item in items.splitlines():
    if item in category:
        Category = Category.set_value(i, item)
        i += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(Category)
print(df)
```

Desired DataFrame Output:

```
Category    Item
Fruits      apple
            orange
            pear
Vegetables  broccoli
            squash
            carrot
Meats       chicken
            beef
            lamb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider appending iteratively to a dictionary of lists instead of series. Then, cast dict to dataframe. Below *key* is used to output desired result as you need a numeric for such a grouping:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txtobj = StringIO('''Fruits
apple
orange
pear
Vegetables
broccoli
squash
carrot
Meats
chicken
beef
lamb''')

items = {'Category':[], 'Item':[]}

for line in txtobj:
    curr_line = line.replace('\n','')
    if curr_line in ['Fruits','Vegetables', 'Meats']:
        curr_category = curr_line       

    if curr_category != curr_line:      
        items['Category'].append(curr_category)
        items['Item'].append(curr_line)

df = pd.DataFrame(items).assign(key=1)
print(df)
#      Category      Item  key
# 0      Fruits     apple    1
# 1      Fruits    orange    1
# 2      Fruits      pear    1
# 3  Vegetables  broccoli    1
# 4  Vegetables    squash    1
# 5  Vegetables    carrot    1
# 6       Meats   chicken    1
# 7       Meats      beef    1
# 8       Meats      lamb    1

print(df['key'].groupby([df['Category'], df['Item']]).count())    
# Category    Item    
# Fruits      apple       1
#             orange      1
#             pear        1
# Meats       beef        1
#             chicken     1
#             lamb        1
# Vegetables  broccoli    1
#             carrot      1
#             squash      1
# Name: key, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

- create mask by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check categories
- [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) new column  by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) and `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with method `ffill`)
- remove same values in both columns by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for unique monotonic default index.

---

```
category = ['Fruits', 'Vegetables', 'Meats']

items='''Fruits
apple
orange
pear
Vegetables
broccoli
squash
carrot
Meats
chicken
beef
lamb'''

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit':items.splitlines()})

mask = df['Fruit'].isin(category)
df.insert(0,'Category', df['Fruit'].where(mask).ffill())
df = df[df['Category'] != df['Fruit']].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     Category     Fruit
0      Fruits     apple
1      Fruits    orange
2      Fruits      pear
3  Vegetables  broccoli
4  Vegetables    squash
5  Vegetables    carrot
6       Meats   chicken
7       Meats      beef
8       Meats      lamb
```

Last if necessary count `Categories` and `Fruits` use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Category','Fruit']).size()
print (df1)
Category    Fruit   
Fruits      apple       1
            orange      1
            pear        1
Meats       beef        1
            chicken     1
            lamb        1
Vegetables  broccoli    1
            carrot      1
            squash      1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without for loops using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
category = ['Fruits', 'Vegetables', 'Meats']

items='''Fruits
apple
orange
pear
Vegetables
broccoli
squash
carrot
Meats
chicken
beef
lamb'''

in_df = pd.DataFrame(items.splitlines())
```

Create groups base on whether that row is in category or not.

```
in_df = in_df.assign(group=in_df.isin(category).cumsum())
```

Create a dataframe from the first row in each group

```
cat_df = in_df.groupby('group').first()
```

Join the second row of each group back to the first row, creating the cateogry fruit relationship

```
df_out = in_df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x[1:]).reset_index(drop = True).merge(cat_df, left_on='group', right_index=True)
```

Drop grouping key and rename columns

```
df_out = df_out.drop('group',axis=1).rename(columns={'0_x':'Fruit','0_y':'Category'})
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
      Fruit    Category
0     apple      Fruits
1    orange      Fruits
2      pear      Fruits
3  broccoli  Vegetables
4    squash  Vegetables
5    carrot  Vegetables
6   chicken       Meats
7      beef       Meats
8      lamb       Meats
```