# Pandas DataFrame find the max after Groupby two columns and get counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe df as following:

```
   userId  pageId  tag
0  3122471  e852   18
1  3122471  f3e2   18
2  3122471  7e93   18
3  3122471  2768    6
4  3122471  53d9    6
5  3122471  06d7   15
6  3122471  e31c   15
7  3122471  c6f3    2
8  1234123  fjwe    1
9  1234123  eiae    4
10 1234123  ieha    4
```

After using `df.groupby(['userId', 'tag'])['pageId'].count()` to group the data by userId and tag . 
I will get:

```
userId   tag
3122471  2      1
         6      2
         15     2
         18     3
1234123   1     1
          4     2
```

Now I want to find the tag that each user has the most.
Just as following:

```
userId   tag
3122471  18
1234123   4
```

(Note: if there are multiple tags that has the same count, I want to use a function `my_rule` to determine which to show)

Comment: I need to know which tag has the most frequency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could work on aggregated data.

```
In [387]: dff = df.groupby(['userId', 'tag'], as_index=False)['pageId'].count()

In [388]: dff
Out[388]:
    userId  tag  pageId
0  1234123    1       1
1  1234123    4       2
2  3122471    2       1
3  3122471    6       2
4  3122471   15       2
5  3122471   18       3

In [389]: dff.groupby('userId').apply(lambda x: x.tag[x.pageId.idxmax()])
Out[389]:
userId
1234123     4
3122471    18
dtype: int64
```

Comment: BTW `df.groupby(['userId'], as_index=False)['tag'].max()` seems to output the largest tag id not the most frequency tag?

Answer (score 2):

group the original dataframe by userid

```
 df.groupby('userId').max()['tag']
```

or

```
 df.groupby('userId', as_index=False)['tag'].max()
```

Note that the second solution is a factor of two faster

```
%timeit df.groupby('userId').max()['tag']
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.69 ms per loop
%timeit df.groupby('userId', as_index=False)['tag'].max()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.43 ms per loop
```

Comment: `df.groupby('userId', as_index=False)['tag'].max()` would be better?

Comment: Sure, it might be faster with large datasets

Comment: I wonder the difference between `df.groupby('userId').max()['tag']` and `df.groupby('userId', as_index=False)['tag'].max()` ?

Comment: Former does `max` operation on all columns except `userId`, later does `max` on `tag` alone.

Comment: This is NOT working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), but first [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

```
df = df.groupby(['userId', 'tag'])['pageId'].size()
df = df.reset_index(level='userId')
      .groupby('userId')['pageId'].idxmax().reset_index(name='tag')
print (df)
    userId  tag
0  1234123    4
1  3122471   18
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(N, 3)), columns= ['userId','pageId','tag'])
#print (df)

In [188]: %timeit (df.groupby(['userId', 'tag'], as_index=False)['pageId'].count().groupby('userId').apply(lambda x: x.tag[x.pageId.idxmax()]))
10 loops, best of 3: 180 ms per loop

In [189]: %timeit (df.groupby(['userId', 'tag'])['pageId'].size().reset_index(level='userId').groupby('userId')['pageId'].idxmax())
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
```

VinceP solution is wrong, so no include to timings.