# Pandas - Sorting Dataframe on index (with words)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I have converted the dates into months, changed the numbers to strings i.e. Apr, May. I then grouped by months to have a smaller dataset. However, the months are in the wrong order and I want to get them to go from April to March.

I wanted to sort by column, but it seems that the month is no longer a column after I grouped it, so I presume it is an index.

This is my code:

```
aDF = pd.DataFrame(e)
rgDF = aDF[['GrantRefNumber','Call','FirstReceivedDate','TotalGrantValue']]
rgaDF = rgDF.drop('GrantRefNumber',1)
rgbDF = rgaDF.drop('Call',1)

rgbDF['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(rgbDF['FirstReceivedDate']).month
rgbDF['month'] = rgbDF['month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])

gA = rgbDF.groupby('month').agg({'TotalGrantValue':sum, 'FirstReceivedDate':'count'}).rename(columns={'FirstReceivedDate':'Count'})
gA['TotalGrantValue'] = gA['TotalGrantValue'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

Which produces this:

```
Count   TotalGrantValue
        month       
        Apr 29  14,039,166.51
        Aug 32  15,340,273.93
        Dec 28  14,801,964.91
        Feb 28  15,946,952.06
        Jan 33  17,820,324.72
        Jul 31  16,870,364.57
        Jun 37  18,472,945.88
        Mar 39  22,387,224.85
        May 24  11,517,789.48
        Nov 31  16,761,506.64
        Oct 28  12,965,535.58
        Sep 34  16,752,631.34
```

I am trying this, but it isnt working (throwing errors):

```
gA.sort_index(by=['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'])
gA
```

FULL ERROR:

```
KeyErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-66c4870a7499> in <module>()
      9 
     10 vals = ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
---> 11 gA = gA.set_index('month').reindex(a).reset_index()

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
   2926                 names.append(None)
   2927             else:
-> 2928                 level = frame[col]._values
   2929                 names.append(col)
   2930                 if drop:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   2060             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2061         else:
-> 2062             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2063 
   2064     def _getitem_column(self, key):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2067         # get column
   2068         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2069             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2070 
   2071         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1532         res = cache.get(item)
   1533         if res is None:
-> 1534             values = self._data.get(item)
   1535             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1536             cache[item] = res

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3588 
   3589             if not isnull(item):
-> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3591             else:
   3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2394             except KeyError:
-> 2395                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2396 
   2397         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5239)()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5085)()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20405)()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20359)()

KeyError: 'month'
```

Comment: Instead of voting down, you could add a comment why you did. It isnt very helpful for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for convert to `months`:

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

```
#sample data
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=20, freq='20d')
aDF = pd.DataFrame({'FirstReceivedDate': rng, 'TotalGrantValue': range(20)})  
print (aDF)
   FirstReceivedDate  TotalGrantValue
0         2017-04-03                0
1         2017-04-23                1
2         2017-05-13                2
3         2017-06-02                3
4         2017-06-22                4
5         2017-07-12                5
6         2017-08-01                6
7         2017-08-21                7
8         2017-09-10                8
9         2017-09-30                9
10        2017-10-20               10
11        2017-11-09               11
12        2017-11-29               12
13        2017-12-19               13
14        2018-01-08               14
15        2018-01-28               15
16        2018-02-17               16
17        2018-03-09               17
18        2018-03-29               18
19        2018-04-18               19
```

---

```
#filter only data what need, so drop is not necessary     
rgbDF = aDF[['FirstReceivedDate','TotalGrantValue']]

rgbDF['month'] = pd.to_datetime(rgbDF['FirstReceivedDate']).dt.strftime('%b')

gA = rgbDF.groupby('month') \
          .agg({'TotalGrantValue':'sum', 'FirstReceivedDate':'count'}) \
          .rename(columns={'FirstReceivedDate':'Count'})

gA['TotalGrantValue'] = gA['TotalGrantValue'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
print (gA)
      TotalGrantValue  Count
month                       
Apr             20.00      3
Aug             38.00      3
Dec             13.00      1
Feb             16.00      1
Jan             29.00      2
Jul             52.00      3
Jun             29.00      3
Mar             35.00      2
May             43.00      3
Nov             52.00      3
Oct             38.00      2
Sep             70.00      4
```

After [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `months` is possible use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by custom list:

```
vals = ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
gA = gA.reindex(vals)
print (gA)
      TotalGrantValue  Count
month                       
Apr             20.00      3
May              2.00      1
Jun              7.00      2
Jul              5.00      1
Aug             13.00      2
Sep             17.00      2
Oct             10.00      1
Nov             23.00      2
Dec             13.00      1
Jan             29.00      2
Feb             16.00      1
Mar             35.00      2
```

Another solution is use [ordered categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) with catagories in list, so after `groupby` output is sorted as you need:

```
rgbDF = aDF[['FirstReceivedDate','TotalGrantValue']]

vals = ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
rgbDF['month'] = pd.Categorical(rgbDF['FirstReceivedDate'].dt.strftime('%b'), 
                                 categories=vals, ordered=True) 

gA = rgbDF.groupby('month')
          .agg({'TotalGrantValue':'sum', 'FirstReceivedDate':'count'})
          .rename(columns={'FirstReceivedDate':'Count'})
gA['TotalGrantValue'] = gA['TotalGrantValue'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
print (gA)
      TotalGrantValue  Count
month                       
Apr             20.00      3
May              2.00      1
Jun              7.00      2
Jul              5.00      1
Aug             13.00      2
Sep             17.00      2
Oct             10.00      1
Nov             23.00      2
Dec             13.00      1
Jan             29.00      2
Feb             16.00      1
Mar             35.00      2
```

Comment: Hey Jezreal. Thank you, I will try it now :)

Comment: Hmm, I am getting the same error. A keyword error of month (ill add the full text to the question now). It has in red about duplicate columns

Comment: Ill try your new fix. Thank you! :)

Comment: |Yes, please try it. Untested yet.

Comment: I am getting a 'OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-06-01 00:00:00' error. I have edited my original post to include my full code for the dataframe.

Comment: Ok, give me some time.

Comment: I think it is possible use both solutions, please check answer.

Comment: Hey, I am getting the following errors on both examples. C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: I am sorry for taking up your time. What change do I need to make? :)

Comment: I think you need `rgbDF = aDF[['FirstReceivedDate','TotalGrantValue']].copy()`

Comment: Ha, now I am getting 'TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__' :)

Comment: It seems some typo. What row?

Comment: maybe `()` are missing I guess

Comment: Yep. It was the () on the copy. Thank you so much again! :D

Answer (score 1):

A small change in Jezrael's answer will work in your case:

```
  gA = rgbDF.groupby('month').agg({'TotalGrantValue':sum, 'FirstReceivedDate':'count'}).rename(columns={'FirstReceivedDate':'Count'})
  gA['TotalGrantValue'] = gA['TotalGrantValue'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
  vals = ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
  gA = gA.set_index(gA.index).reindex(vals).reset_index()
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you :)