# How to plot pandas groupby values in a graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, bar-chart

I have a csv file which contains Gender and Marriage status along with few more columns like below.

```
Loan_ID,Gender,Married,Dependents,Education,Self_Employed,ApplicantIncome,CoapplicantIncome,LoanAmount,Loan_Amount_Term,Credit_History,Property_Area,Loan_Status
LP001002,Male,No,0,Graduate,No,5849,0,,360,1,Urban,Y
LP001003,Male,Yes,1,Graduate,No,4583,1508,128,360,1,Rural,N
LP001005,Male,Yes,0,Graduate,Yes,3000,0,66,360,1,Urban,Y
LP001006,Male,Yes,0,Not Graduate,No,2583,2358,120,360,1,Urban,Y
LP001008,Male,No,0,Graduate,No,6000,0,141,360,1,Urban,Y
LP001011,Male,Yes,2,Graduate,Yes,5417,4196,267,360,1,Urban,Y
```

I want to count no. of married Males and Females and show the same in graph as shown below

Below is the code I am using :

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=[]
    y=[]
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "/home/train.csv",usecols=[1,2]).dropna(subset=['Gender','Married'])  # Reading the dataset in a dataframe using Pandas
    groups = df.groupby(['Gender','Married'])['Married'].apply(lambda x: x.count())
    print(groups)
```

After group by I have following result :

```
Gender  Married
Female  No          80
        Yes         31
Male    No         130
        Yes        357
```

I want the following chart

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and then use [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

[Difference between count and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas).

```
groups = df.groupby(['Gender','Married']).size()
groups.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

Another solution is add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape or [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['Gender','Married']).size().unstack(fill_value=0))
Married   No  Yes
Gender           
Female    80   31
Male     130  357

df.groupby(['Gender','Married']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).plot.bar()
```

Or:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Gender'],df['Married']).plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Do you use spyder/anaconda ?

Comment: But I think you can use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` first, then `df.groupby(['Gender','Married']).size().unstack(fill_value=0‌​).plot.bar()` and last `plt.show()`

Comment: could you please explain what is happening in the above solution? 

df.groupby(['Gender','Married']).size().unstack(fill_value=0) this line. What will unstack do here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `unstack` function get same lebel of multiindex (`'column' Married`) and pivot table - create column names and reorder data by it. It is called pivoting.