# Fitting multiple curves or representing in heat map

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, curve-fitting

I have two columns , I have tried this:

```
df[['EYE_WIDTH','LANE']].groupby(['EYE_WIDTH','LANE']).size().unstack()
```

Now I got this table:

```
LANE          0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8   \
EYE_WIDTH                                                                  
31.2         NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN   
35.1         NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    1.0    NaN   
39.0         NaN    1.0    NaN    2.0    NaN    NaN    2.0    1.0    NaN   
42.9         1.0    5.0    5.0   10.0    2.0    5.0    9.0   17.0    3.0   
46.8        19.0   14.0   17.0   23.0   27.0   31.0   42.0   39.0   27.0   
50.7        84.0   48.0   63.0   93.0   69.0   95.0  137.0  130.0   99.0   
54.6       204.0  173.0  176.0  206.0  158.0  158.0  207.0  182.0  199.0   
58.5       350.0  308.0  296.0  284.0  257.0  214.0  237.0  228.0  235.0   
62.4       282.0  278.0  242.0  257.0  275.0  236.0  259.0  206.0  237.0   
66.3       112.0  180.0  212.0  167.0  213.0  244.0  152.0  223.0  197.0   
70.2        26.0   64.0   65.0   41.0   80.0   91.0   39.0   59.0   76.0   
74.1         2.0   11.0    4.0    1.0    5.0    9.0    2.0    1.0    3.0   
78.0         NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    1.0   

LANE          9      10     11     12     13     14     15  
EYE_WIDTH                                                   
31.2         NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
35.1         NaN    1.0    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN  
39.0         3.0    3.0    3.0    2.0    3.0    6.0    NaN  
42.9        11.0    6.0    7.0    3.0   14.0    7.0    7.0  
46.8        43.0   39.0   41.0   15.0   16.0   29.0   35.0  
50.7       101.0  114.0  144.0   56.0   78.0   96.0  116.0  
54.6       206.0  210.0  193.0  187.0  158.0  186.0  283.0  
58.5       275.0  231.0  246.0  251.0  278.0  295.0  344.0  
62.4       219.0  233.0  217.0  203.0  278.0  257.0  212.0  
66.3       167.0  196.0  163.0  243.0  197.0  161.0   73.0  
70.2        50.0   46.0   58.0   99.0   53.0   40.0   10.0  
74.1         2.0    3.0    5.0   20.0    5.0    4.0    1.0  
78.0         NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Now i want to visualize these relationship ,one thing i have in mind is fitting them along curves like below [image]
along with that it is good if I can also represent them in heatmap.

First few lines of data

```
   EYE_WIDTH  LANE
     66.3    11
     58.5    12
     70.2    13
     66.3     7
     58.5    14
     58.5     0
     62.4     1
     62.4     2
     54.6     3
     62.4     4
     58.5     5
     50.7     6
     62.4    15
     66.3     8
     70.2     9
     58.5    10
     66.3     1
     58.5     7
     66.3     8
     50.7     9
     62.4     0
     62.4    11
     62.4    12
     66.3    13
     66.3    15
     58.5    10
     50.7     2
     58.5     3
     54.6     4
     50.7     5
     50.7     6
     58.5    14
     62.4     1
     62.4     2
     62.4     3
     62.4     4
     54.6     5
     62.4     6
     58.5     7
     62.4     8
     66.3     9
     62.4    10
     62.4    11
     62.4    12
     62.4    13
     54.6     0
     66.3    15
     62.4    14
     58.5    15
     54.6    13
```

So there are 13 distinct EYE_WIDTH values and 16 distinct LANE ,now by using groupby and size unstack , I got to know that how number of times each lane is  associated with the distinct EYE_WIDTH. Now I need to visualize this relationship

I tried:

```
df[['EYE_WIDTH','LANE']].groupby(['EYE_WIDTH','LANE']).size().unstack().plot()
```

[image]

Comment: It would really help if you provided more complete code (including imported libraries), and data in text format. For example the output of `print(df[['EYE_WIDTH','LANE']])`. What did you try already?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added first 20 rows of eyewidth and lane. Yes , I tried to build them as a group as you can see above. Now I am stuck in visualizing them

Comment: Please put it in text format, not an image. And preferrably more than just 20 rows. Maybe better the output of `print(df[['EYE_WIDTH','LANE']].groupby(['EYE_WIDTH','LANE']).size().unstack())` as text.

Comment: Did you at least try something such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299305/how-to-plot-pandas-groupby-values-in-a-graph) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942755/plotting-multiple-time-series-after-a-groupby-in-pandas/52526454#52526454)? Or this [blog post](https://scentellegher.github.io/programming/2017/07/15/pandas-groupby-multiple-columns-plot.html)?

Comment: I edited now, is it sufficient

Comment: I got the idea from your post suggestions, I appreciate but I am just wondering is there a better comprehensive way to visualize that data. It seems messy so far for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way to find structure in the data is to try out different visualizations. The visualization you obtained from the pandas plot command already suggests that there isn't much difference between each of the 'lanes'.

Here is some code to draw a smooth line plot and a heatmap of the given data. As in the straight line plot, the data don't seem to indicate much influence of the lane parameter. The straight line plot is more "honest", as it jus shows the pure data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import NaN
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

eye_width = [31.2, 35.1, 39.0, 42.9, 46.8, 50.7, 54.6, 58.5, 62.4, 66.3, 70.2, 74.1, 78.0]
rows = np.array([
    [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN],
    [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.0, NaN, 1.0, NaN, NaN, 1.0, NaN, 1.0, NaN, NaN, NaN],
    [NaN, 1.0, NaN, 2.0, NaN, NaN, 2.0, 1.0, NaN, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0, NaN],
    [1.0, 5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 2.0, 5.0, 9.0, 17.0, 3.0, 11.0, 6.0, 7.0, 3.0, 14.0, 7.0, 7.0],
    [19.0, 14.0, 17.0, 23.0, 27.0, 31.0, 42.0, 39.0, 27.0, 43.0, 39.0, 41.0, 15.0, 16.0, 29.0, 35.0],
    [84.0, 48.0, 63.0, 93.0, 69.0, 95.0, 137.0, 130.0, 99.0, 101.0, 114.0, 144.0, 56.0, 78.0, 96.0, 116.0],
    [204.0, 173.0, 176.0, 206.0, 158.0, 158.0, 207.0, 182.0, 199.0, 206.0, 210.0, 193.0, 187.0, 158.0, 186.0, 283.0],
    [350.0, 308.0, 296.0, 284.0, 257.0, 214.0, 237.0, 228.0, 235.0, 275.0, 231.0, 246.0, 251.0, 278.0, 295.0, 344.0],
    [282.0, 278.0, 242.0, 257.0, 275.0, 236.0, 259.0, 206.0, 237.0, 219.0, 233.0, 217.0, 203.0, 278.0, 257.0, 212.0],
    [112.0, 180.0, 212.0, 167.0, 213.0, 244.0, 152.0, 223.0, 197.0, 167.0, 196.0, 163.0, 243.0, 197.0, 161.0, 73.0],
    [26.0, 64.0, 65.0, 41.0, 80.0, 91.0, 39.0, 59.0, 76.0, 50.0, 46.0, 58.0, 99.0, 53.0, 40.0, 10.0],
    [2.0, 11.0, 4.0, 1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 20.0, 5.0, 4.0, 1.0],
    [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.0, NaN, 1.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows)
df['eye_width'] = eye_width
df.set_index(['eye_width'], inplace=True)
df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
x = np.linspace(min(eye_width), max(eye_width), 1000)
for i in range(0, 16, 3):
    # ax.plot(df.index, df[i], label=f'Lane {i}')
    interpolation = interp1d(df.index, df[i], kind='cubic')
    ax.plot(x, interpolation(x), label=f'Lane {i}')
ax.legend(loc='best')

img = ax2.imshow(rows, origin='lower')
ax2.set_xticks(range(16))
ax2.set_yticks(range(len(eye_width)))
ax2.set_yticklabels(eye_width)
plt.colorbar(img, ax=ax2)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]