# Using Pandas Data Frame how to apply count to multi level grouped columns?

Tags: python, pandas, count, multi-level, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with multiple columns and I want to use count after group by such that it is applied to the combination of 2 or more columns. for example, let's say I have two columns:

```
user_id  product_name
1        Apple
1        Banana
1        Apple
2        Carrot
2        Tomato
2        Carrot
2        Tomato 
3        Milk
3        Cucumber
```

...

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
user_id  product_name Product_Count_per_User
1        Apple        1 
1        Banana       2
2        Carrot       2
2        Tomato       2
3        Milk         1
3        Cucumber     1
```

I cannot get it. I tried this:

```
dcf6 = df3.groupby(['user_id','product_name'])['user_id', 'product_name'].count()
```

but it does not seem to get what I want and it is displaying 4 columns instead of 3. How to do to it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting two columns at the same time, you can just use `groupby.size`:

```
(df.groupby(['user_id', 'Product_Name']).size()
   .rename('Product_Count_per_User').reset_index())
```

[image]

Or count only one column:

```
df.groupby(['user_id','Product_Name'])['user_id'].size()
```

Comment: Hmmm, count is used for non NaNs counting, so here better is size.

Comment: @jezrael Sure. But `groupby` drops `nan` values by default, so I guess it doesn't matter that much in this case now, as he is counting the group variables anyway. But I agree `size` is a better choice here.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
dcf6 = df3.groupby(['user_id','Product_Name']).size()
          .reset_index(name='Product_Count_per_User')
print (dcf6)
   user_id Product_Name  Product_Count_per_User
0        1        Apple                       2
1        1       Banana                       1
2        2       Carrot                       2
3        2       Tomato                       2
4        3     Cucumber                       1
5        3         Milk                       1
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Base on your own code , just do this .

```
df.groupby(['user_id','product_name'])['user_id'].
          agg({'Product_Count_per_User':'count'}).reset_index(level=1)

        product_name  Product_Count_per_User
user_id                      
1              Apple        2
1             Banana        1
2             Carrot        2
2             Tomato        2
3           Cucumber        1
3               Milk        1
```