# Add prefix failed with percentage

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, prefix

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,4], 'b':[7,8]})
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  7
1  4  8
```

I try add `%` to columns names, so use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)

```
print (df.add_prefix('%'))
```

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

What can be problem?

How is possible use `add_prefix` function with `%` ?

Or it is only bug?

*Notice*:

Possible solution is like:

```
df.columns = ['%' + col for col in df.columns]
print (df)
   %a  %b
0   1   7
1   4   8
```

but I am interested about function `add_prefix`.

Comment: Perhaps a bug?  The *mapper* is `f = (str(prefix) + '%s').__mod__` on line 2593 (pandas 0.17.1) of `/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py`.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/9b07ef4a5b656a1532512c270533053ee338e30d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE:**
This is likely to change in the near future as `pandas` will use new style string formatting in this case.  When that happens:

```
'{}hello'.format('%')

'%hello'
```

adding a prefix with a single `%` will work just fine.

[See github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/9b07ef4a5b656a1532512c270533053ee338e30d)

---

**Answer**
Two percent signs!  One escapes the other when using the old style of string formatting.

```
df.add_prefix('%%')

   %a  %b
0   1   7
1   4   8
```

---

The clue came from:

> ```
>    2856     def add_prefix(self, prefix):
>    2857         f = (str(prefix) + '%s').__mod__
> -> 2858         return self.rename_axis(f, axis=0)
>    2859 
>    2860     def add_suffix(self, suffix):
> ```

So I tried it myself

```
f = ('my_prefix_' + '%s').__mod__
f('hello')

'my_prefix_hello'
```

And then

```
f = ('%' + '%s').__mod__
f('hello')
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-901-0c92e5498bbc> in <module>()
>       1 f = ('%' + '%s').__mod__
> ----> 2 f('hello')
>
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> ```

So I looked up how to escape the `'%'` in the old style of string formatting and found [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10678240/2336654)

Which led to this

```
f = ('%%' + '%s').__mod__
f('hello')

'%hello'
```

Comment: I tried the same exact thing.  In fact, I have one attempt, out of frustration, using `r'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\%'`