# Pandas unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' with pandas groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am stuck on probably an elementary problem with pandas DataFrame. In the following code snippet, I insert a calculated column 'CAPACITY_CHECK' then I try to group by the data based on it. But I keep having the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

```js
TEMP['CAPACITY_CHECK'] = TEMP[['ADD_CAPACITY_ST', 'CAPACITY_ST', 'VOLUME_PER_SUPPLIER']].apply(lambda X: numpy.where(X[0]+X[1]<X[2],'Non OK', 'OK'), axis=1)
TEMP.groupby('CAPACITY_CHECK')['ID'].count()
```

Since I am not trying to modify any immutable object and the new column's type is "Series", I don't understand why I am having the error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need remove apply and working only with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = (TEMP['ADD_CAPACITY_ST'] + TEMP['CAPACITY_ST']) < TEMP['VOLUME_PER_SUPPLIER']
TEMP['CAPACITY_CHECK'] = numpy.where(mask,'Non OK', 'OK')
```

**Sample**:

```
TEMP = pd.DataFrame({'ADD_CAPACITY_ST':[10,20,30],
                     'CAPACITY_ST':[10,20,30],
                     'VOLUME_PER_SUPPLIER':[40,20,100]})

mask = (TEMP['ADD_CAPACITY_ST'] + TEMP['CAPACITY_ST']) < TEMP['VOLUME_PER_SUPPLIER']
TEMP['CAPACITY_CHECK'] = numpy.where(mask,'Non OK', 'OK')
print (TEMP)
   ADD_CAPACITY_ST  CAPACITY_ST  VOLUME_PER_SUPPLIER CAPACITY_CHECK
0               10           10                   40         Non OK
1               20           20                   20             OK
2               30           30                  100         Non OK
```

Then use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) or [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
TEMP.groupby('CAPACITY_CHECK')['ID'].size()

TEMP.groupby('CAPACITY_CHECK')['ID'].count()
```

[Difference between count and size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33346694/2901002).