# Pandas, groupby and count

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe say like this

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':['a','a','s','s','s'],
                    'session':[4,5,4,5,5],
                    'revenue':[-1,0,1,2,1]})

>>> df
   revenue  session user_id
0       -1        4       a
1        0        5       a
2        1        4       s
3        2        5       s
4        1        5       s
```

And each value of session and revenue represents a kind of type, and I want to count the number of each kind say the number of `revenue=-1` and `session=4` of `user_id=a` is 1.

And I found simple call `count()` function after `groupby()` can't output the result I want.

```
>>> df.groupby('user_id').count()
         revenue  session
user_id
a              2        2
s              3        3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: from pandas 1.1 this is made possible with [`df.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts), allowing you to avoid the grouping step.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You seem to want to group by several columns at once:

```
df.groupby(['revenue','session','user_id'])['user_id'].count()
```

should give you what you want

Answer (score 53):

## pandas >= 1.1: [`df.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts) is available!

From pandas 1.1, this will be my recommended method for counting the number of rows in groups (i.e., the group size). To count the number of non-nan rows in a group *for a specific column*, check out the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320593/4909087).

Old

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size()   # df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].count()
```

**New** [✓]

```
df.value_counts(subset=['A', 'B'])
```

Note that `size` and `count` are not identical, the former counts all rows per group, the latter counts non-null rows only. See [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364400/4909087) for more.

---

#### Minimal Example

```
pd.__version__
# '1.1.0.dev0+2004.g8d10bfb6f'

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 4, 6],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'cat', 'ant'])
df
        num_legs  num_wings
falcon         2          2
dog            4          0
cat            4          0
ant            6          0
```

```
df.value_counts(subset=['num_legs', 'num_wings'], sort=False)

num_legs  num_wings
2         2            1
4         0            2
6         0            1
dtype: int64
```

Compare this output with

```
df.groupby(['num_legs', 'num_wings'])['num_legs'].size()

num_legs  num_wings
2         2            1
4         0            2
6         0            1
Name: num_legs, dtype: int64
```

---

#### Performance

It's also faster if you don't sort the result:

```
%timeit df.groupby(['num_legs', 'num_wings'])['num_legs'].count()
%timeit df.value_counts(subset=['num_legs', 'num_wings'], sort=False)

640 µs ± 28.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
568 µs ± 6.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: When I use `subset` with `value_counts` and do a print, I lose the column titles; any idea why this could be?

Comment: Having the same problem as @FMFF. I'm loosing the columns i grouped by. They are instead functioning as the index in the form of 'columnA/columnB'

Comment: @petzholt What about using `as_index=False` as an argument to `groupby`?

Comment: @FMFF I simply call `.to_frame()` when I want the index to create a new `df`. In this case it would be: `df.value_counts(subset=['num_legs', 'num_wings'], sort=False).to_frame()`

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with the same issue, made use of the solution provided above. You can actually designate any of the columns to count:

```
df.groupby(['revenue','session','user_id'])['revenue'].count()
```

and

```
df.groupby(['revenue','session','user_id'])['session'].count()
```

would give the same answer.

Comment: This is true only if all columns contain the same number of non-NA values.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, you cannot designate _any_ column for the "count", since count() only counts non-null values and different columns can have different nan counts. If you are looking to count the number of rows in each group, use [`df.value_counts(subset=['...])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts) instead (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62802626/4909087)).