# Select the sum of column values based on a certain value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]
Hi,

I'm a beginner in learning how to represent data (in this example, coronavirus deaths) with Python. To do that I use certain libraries like pandas, seaborn, ...

In a circle diagram, I want to display the percentage of total deaths seperated by Female and Male, but I don't really know how to achieve this yet. In online documentation I don't really find much information about this.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320572/pandas-groupby-and-count to see how to group by column 'SEX' and count how many M and how many F.  Once you have some code going, we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
df.groupby('SEX')["DEATHS"].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

We present the code that produces the composition ratio.

```
df.groupby('SEX').sum().apply(lambda x: x / sum(x))

df
    DEATHS
SEX 
F   0.75
M   0.25
```