# Get the count for each subgroup in a multiple grouped pandas.DateFrame aggregated on one group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns "A" and "B".

```
   A          B   
0  foo      one 
1  bar      one 
2  foo      two 
3  bar      one
4  foo      two 
5  bar      two 
6  foo      one 
7  foo      one
8  xyz      one
```

For each group in "A", I'm trying to get the count of each value of "B", i.e. each sub-group of B, but aggregated on the grouping of "A".

The result should look like this:

```
   A          B   countOne  countTwo
0  foo      one          3         2
1  bar      one          2         1
2  foo      two          3         2
3  bar      one          2         1
4  foo      two          3         2
5  bar      two          2         1
6  foo      one          3         2
7  foo      one          3         2
8  xyz      one          1         0
```

I have tried several approaches to no avail, so far I'm using this approach:

```
A_grouped = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['A'].count()
A_grouped_ones = A_grouped[:,'one']
A_grouped_twos = A_grouped[:,'two']
df['countOne'] = df['A'].map(lambda a: A_grouped_ones[a] if a in A_grouped_ones else 0)
df['countTwo'] = df['A'].map(lambda a: A_grouped_twos[a] if a in A_grouped_twos else 0)
```

However, this seems horribly inefficient two me. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for new `DataFrame` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['A'].count().unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('count_')
print (df1)
B    count_one  count_two
A                        
bar          2          1
foo          3          2
xyz          1          0

df = df.join(df1, on='A')
print (df)
     A    B  count_one  count_two
0  foo  one          3          2
1  bar  one          2          1
2  foo  two          3          2
3  bar  one          2          1
4  foo  two          3          2
5  bar  two          2          1
6  foo  one          3          2
7  foo  one          3          2
8  xyz  one          1          0
```

Another alternative is use `size`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('count_')
```

Differences are [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) includes `NaN` values, [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count) does not - check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33346694/2901002).