# Python-pandas counting by groupby inaccuracy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
def comment (row):
    if row['STATUS'] == "CANCELLED":
        return "Cancelled"
    elif  strToDate(row['PROCESS_DATE']) < datetime(2018,1,1) or strToDate(row['PROCESS_DATE']) > datetime(2018,2,1):
        return "Date out of Range"
    elif "Lost" in str(row['NOTE']) or "Stolen" in str(row['TRADE_NOTE_TXT']):
        return 'Lost or Stolen'
    else:
        return 'Other'

df['Comment'] = ''

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i,"Comment"] = comment(row)
```

I use the following above code to change the value of df['Comment'] based on these conditions. However when I do df.count() it shows there are 7790 values in comment.

However when I do df.groupby('Comment').size() The out put is as follows, which is much greater than the number of comments that should even be present.

```
     Comment
     Cancelled            1171
     Date out of Range    1175
     Lost or Stolen       634
     Other                4810
     dtype: int64
```

Comment: Those numbers add up to the correct amount, I do not see the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am confused as to what it is you're asking but those numbers add up:

`1171 + 1175 + 634 + 4810 = 7790`

Meaning that `df.count()` and `df.groupby('Comment').size()` represent the same number of rows.

Answer (score -1):

You need to first properly indent your code under the `def comment(row):` function to get the answer you expect.

Comment: Sorry that was a copy and paste error, it is indented properly

Comment: I was trying to comment but it would not let me. Was Just trying to help, not get downrated.