# Apply multiple operations on same columns after groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
id    year_month    amount
10    201901        10
10    201901        20
10    201901        30
20    201902        40
20    201902        20
```

I want to `groupby` `id` and `year-month` and then get the group size and sum of `amount`,

```
df.groupby(['id', 'year_month'], as_index=False)['amount'].sum()

df.groupby(['id', 'year_month'], as_index=False).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

I am wondering how to do it at the same time in one line;

```
id    year_month    amount    count
10    201901        60        3
20    201902        60        2
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['id', 'year_month'])['amount'].agg(['sum','size']).reset_index()` do it with `.agg()`

Comment: @anky_91 whats the difference between `size` and `count` for `agg`?

Comment: Actually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas) is a good read for that question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `agg`:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'year_month']).agg({'amount': ['count', 'sum']})


                    amount
                   count    sum
id  year_month      
10  201901          3       60
20  201902          2       60
```

If you want to remove the multi-index, use [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['id', 'year_month']).agg({'amount': ['count', 'sum']}).rename(columns ={'sum': 'amount'})
s.columns = s.columns.droplevel(level=0)
s.reset_index()

    id  year_month  count   amount
0   10  201901        3      60
1   20  201902        2      60
```