# How to change a dataframe to count the variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X":['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a'],
                   "Y":['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A']})
```

Which method can I use to count the similar values and change it like this:

```
   a  b  c
A  2 1 1  
B  0 1 0
C  0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try `crosstab` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)):

```
pd.crosstab(df.Y, df.X)
```

Result:

```
X  a  b  c
Y         
A  2  1  1
B  0  1  0
C  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) method, the first param is the data source, I would think `columns` parameter, `index` parameter and `fill_value` parameter don't need explanation however, I want to clarify something `aggfunc` parameter: 'size' will include `nan` values, if you set this parameter as 'count', then only will count `no-nan` values. You can read more about that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas) answer.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, columns='X', index='Y', fill_value=0, aggfunc='size')
```

Output:

```
X  a  b  c
Y         
A  2  1  1
B  0  1  0
C  0  1  0
```