# Make a new column that's the frequency of a row in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda, tuples

I need a new column `C` where each value is the frequency with which the values in two other columns `A` and `B` appear together in the data.

```
    A   B   C
0   7   9   2
1   7   2   2
2   1   9   3
3   4   8   1
4   9   1   1
5   6   4   1
6   7   2   2
7   7   9   2
8   1   9   3
9   1   9   3
```

I tried making a dictionary out of a value count like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'A': np.random.randint(1, 10, 100),
   'B': np.random.randint(1, 10, 100)
})

mapper = df.value_counts().to_dict()
```

Then I convert each row to a tuple and feed it back through the dictionary in pandas' apply function:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: mapper[tuple(x)], axis=1)
```

This solution seems possibly (a) incorrect or (b) inefficient, and I'm wondering if there's a better way of going about it.

Comment: `df['C'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['B'].transform('size')`

Comment: This worked! Is it completely arbitrary which column is passed from the groupby to transform? (You gave B, could I just as easily give A? Why is this?)

Comment: any column would work, because they do have the same size. I tend to specify one column with `transform` as it *transform* one series/column to another via groupby.

Comment: You tend to? Is it not necessary to specify some column? I tried not specifying a column and got either and error or an empty DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['C2'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['B'].transform('count')
df
```

```
    A   B   C2
0   7   9   2
1   7   2   2
2   1   9   3
3   4   8   1
4   9   1   1
5   6   4   1
6   7   2   2
7   7   9   2
8   1   9   3
9   1   9   3
```

data used for the solution

```
data={'A': {0: 7, 1: 7, 2: 1, 3: 4, 4: 9, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 7, 8: 1, 9: 1},
 'B': {0: 9, 1: 2, 2: 9, 3: 8, 4: 1, 5: 4, 6: 2, 7: 9, 8: 9, 9: 9}}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Comment: What's the difference between using `size` and `count` here? Which is better?

Comment: this should help   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas