# Why pandas pivot_table count over a dataframe with 2 columns works with aggfunc=len, but results in empty dataset with count?

Tags: pandas, count, pivot-table

Why I cannot replace the `len` below with `"count"` and keep same output behavior?. I mean, it runs without error, but the output is ***very different***, if I change the `len` to `count`, I get an ***empty*** dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
        'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='Category', columns='Value', values='Value', aggfunc=len)

print(pivot_table)
```

Results in:

```
Value      10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90
Category                                             
A         1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
B         NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
C         NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

`size` produces same result as len:

```
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='Category', columns='Value', values='Value', aggfunc="size")
```

Even weirder, I can make "count" work like "size" (or len) if I do this strange workaround: create a copy of Value with a different "ValueCopy" name :

```
df["ValueCopy"] = df["Value"]
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='Category', columns='Value', values='ValueCopy', aggfunc="count")
```

But if I change the `pivot_table` call to use `"count"` without the extra dummy column workaround:

```
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='Category', columns='Value', values='Value', aggfunc="count")
```

it results in:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [A, B, C]
```

Questions:

- Have I hit a Pandas bug?
- Is this expected Pandas behavior?
- How does `"count"` work if it does not call `len`? (I tried to read the [pivot_table Pandas code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py), but I found it too convoluted)
- Why creating a dummy copy of the value column makes count work like size (and len) ?
- Is the fact that count works fine in Polars & DuckDb indicative of this being a defect in Pandas? (see below)

---

In **Polars**, "count" works perfectly fine as:

```
import polars as pl

# Create a DataFrame
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

# Pivot the DataFrame
pivot_table = df.pivot(index='Category', columns='Value', values='Value', aggregate_function="count")

# Print the pivot table
print(pivot_table)
```

results in:

```
Shape: (3, 10)
┌──────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Category ┆ 10   ┆ 20   ┆ 30   ┆ … ┆ 60   ┆ 70   ┆ 80   ┆ 90   │
│ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str      ┆ u32  ┆ u32  ┆ u32  ┆   ┆ u32  ┆ u32  ┆ u32  ┆ u32  │
╞══════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ A        ┆ 1    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ … ┆ null ┆ 1    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ B        ┆ null ┆ 1    ┆ null ┆ … ┆ null ┆ null ┆ 1    ┆ null │
│ C        ┆ null ┆ null ┆ 1    ┆ … ┆ 1    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ 1    │
└──────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

---

Likewise **DuckDb** SQL pivot count has no trouble counting:

```
import pandas as pd
import duckdb

# Your existing DataFrame
data = {'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
        'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a DuckDB connection
con = duckdb.connect()

# Register the DataFrame with DuckDB
con.register('df_pivot', df)

# Perform the pivot operation in DuckDB
query = """

PIVOT df_pivot
ON Value
USING Count(Value)
GROUP BY Category

"""
pivot_table = con.execute(query).fetchdf()

print(pivot_table)
```

results in:

```
  Category  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90
0        A   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
1        B   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
2        C   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

Comment: the code essentially does `df.groupby(['Category', 'Value']).agg('count')` and then transforming the results of that into a pivot table. The issue seems to be - the groupby agg seems to be returning an empty df.

Comment: Weird... right? Strangest part is that if you have 3 columns on the starting dataset and hence you do not need to mention "Values" twice (columns='Value', values='Value'), then aggfunc="count" (seems to?) works fine again 

Comment: see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364400/2214597 specifically the section at the end of it. Edit: Nvm, that says if values is not passed in

Comment: But values are passed in in my code right? I mean, that description sounds related, but explanation there does not seem to match what we are am seeing here... I am unclear on what is the *nothing* in "when nothing is passed, pandas decides to make no assumptions"

Comment: Also, why does the df["ValueCopy"] = df["Value"] trick work to make "count" function again?

Comment: Since count refers to the non-null count, an additional column to count is required. Therefore, there is the `pd.crosstab` function.

Comment: An additional column is indeed required, but I do not understand what you mean by "Since count refers to the non-null count". How can I implement a my_count that is as weird as the built in count?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas By looking at the difference between `size` and `count`, you can better understand the concept of non-null count.

Comment: Why would the behavior of non-null count change just because one adds a dummy column?

Comment: All that has happened is that a new column for counting has been added, and the behavior is not changed.

Comment: The behavior is changed. I add a column, count returns a filled up dataframe, whereas before, it returned empty dataset.

Comment: The behavior hasn't changed. The results are different. It didn't return anything because there were no columns to count non-null for. Now that there are columns to count non-null for, it simply counts the non-null values. I don't think you're making any effort to understand this on your own. I believe I've provided you with resources to understand, but you're generating new questions instead of trying to understand or creating new data to test. I'm not your teacher, so I'm giving up on this question. Just use Polars.

Comment: If the results are different, given same inputs, the behavior has changed. That is elemental logic. The code has run through a different pathway. Otherwise, the results would be the same. In this case, conceptually ValueCopy and Value contain identical data, so they should be interchangable, that is, using either should lead to the same result (as it does in Polars)

Comment: it could be a bug. you can raise an issue on the pandas github page, and if you know the fix for it, you can submit a PR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas, `pivot_table` at some point calls `groupby(index+columns)`.

In your example that means grouping on the only two existing columns, so there are no values to count.

When using `len` in this situation it returns the length of each group as a DataFrame (using `DataFrame.__len__`, which returns `len(self.index)`) -- which IMO seems more odd than returning nothing.

Comment: So, Pandas is letting its idiosyncratic way of doing groupby cause a bug in how pivot_table works?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug or just expected behavior by the Pandas team (you could argue that if you're counting values in empty groups the result shouldn't have anything). In any case, it is being caused by the way Pandas handles `groupby` with `'count'` as an aggregation function, yes.

Comment: As for how it compares with Polars and DuckDb, I don't have experience with them, so I don't how they handle this situation.

Comment: Consider SQL itself: `select category,value,count(*) as cc from data group by category,value` works Ok, as per relational algebra  `π c, v, cv γ c, v; COUNT(*)→cv D` (where c = category and v = value and D is the data table )

Comment: Makes sense. Could be worth raising an issue on Github.

Comment: If you select a column like `groupby(['Category', 'Value'])['Value'].agg('count')` it actually returns what you would expect. If you replace [this line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L170) `agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)` with `agged = grouped[values].agg(aggfunc)`, it "fixes" the issue with `pivot_table`. I don't know if this "fix" could have other implications though, or if maybe this is something that should be fixed in the `groupby` code.