# Reording a stacked dataframe by rank in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have generated a txt file from a stacked dataframe, where the output looks like this:

```
Name    Rank    F   R
Sample1 0   CGGGGT  GGGTTC
Sample1 1   GCTGC   GCTGCGT
Sample1 2   ACGTG   AGCTGA
Sample1 3   CGATCG  AGCTAGC
Sample1 4   CGTCAG  GGCTTT
Sample2 0   AGTCAG  GTCAG
Sample2 1   CGATCA  GCATGCA
Sample2 2   ACTAG   GCATGCA
Sample2 3   ACTAGCA ACACCA
Sample2 4   ACTGTCG CCCAAAT
Sample3 0   GGCAT   TTACTA
Sample3 1   GTCATG  GCTTTA
Sample3 2   GTCAG   TCGTAGC
Sample3 3   GCATGCA GCATGCA
Sample3 4   GTCAG   AATCTC
```

The samples show up 5 times each and have a rank 0-4, 0 being the best and 4 being the worst.I then take the txt into my next function and calculate a frequency, so the updated table has a frequency calculation assigned to it:

```
Name    Rank    F   R   Frequency
Sample1 0   CGGGGT  GGGTTC  5
Sample1 1   GCTGC   GCTGCGT 8
Sample1 2   ACGTG   AGCTGA  2
Sample1 3   CGATCG  AGCTAGC 1
Sample1 4   CGTCAG  GGCTTT  2
Sample2 0   AGTCAG  GTCAG   10
Sample2 1   CGATCA  GCATGCA 5
Sample2 2   ACTAG   GCATGCA 3
Sample2 3   ACTAGCA ACACCA  4
Sample2 4   ACTGTCG CCCAAAT 1
Sample3 0   GGCAT   TTACTA  0
Sample3 1   GTCATG  GCTTTA  0
Sample3 2   GTCAG   TCGTAGC 2
Sample3 3   GCATGCA GCATGCA 3
Sample3 4   GTCAG   AATCTC  4
```

I would like to drop the rank and sort each `Name` group by frequency from lowest to highest. This would be fairly straightforward for me, except I want to keep the samples grouped together.

I tried the following:

```
df = df.drop('Rank', axis=1)

df.groupby('Name').sort_values('Frequency')
```

But I get an error:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

I want the resultant DF to look like:

```
   Name        F        R   Frequency                                                 
Sample1   CGATCG  AGCTAGC          1
Sample1    ACGTG   AGCTGA          2
Sample1   CGTCAG   GGCTTT          2
Sample1   CGGGGT   GGGTTC          5
Sample1    GCTGC  GCTGCGT          8
Sample2  ACTGTCG  CCCAAAT          1
Sample2    ACTAG  GCATGCA          3
Sample2  ACTAGCA   ACACCA          4
Sample2   CGATCA  GCATGCA          5
Sample2   AGTCAG    GTCAG         10
Sample3    GGCAT   TTACTA          0
Sample3   GTCATG   GCTTTA          0
Sample3    GTCAG  TCGTAGC          2
Sample3  GCATGCA  GCATGCA          3
Sample3    GTCAG   AATCTC          4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can sort on multiple columns: `df.drop('Rank', axis=1).sort_values(['Name', 'Frequency'])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018622/pandas-groupby-sort-descending-order/36316186

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the duplicate question.