# Pandas groupby sum and sort descending on that sum

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a `groupby` statement resulting the below result. How can sort the `w` column descending order within that grouping?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code -

```
grouped = df_sp.groupby(['season','home_team']).sum('w').reset_index()
g = grouped.sort_values('w', ascending=False)
```

Ref link - [pandas groupby sort descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018622/pandas-groupby-sort-descending-order)

`pls share reproducible code so that others can test, above code is not tested.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby.apply` with the `sort_values`

```
df_sp.groupby(['season','home_team']).sum('w').apply(lambda x : x['w'].sort_values(ascending=False))
```